# Horrendous decrease in MySQL Performance after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, database-administration

I have a development server that I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.

I have a database 'algebra', which hosts data for my website algebra.com. 
It is a Q&A website that has Questions and Answers, with 1 to N relationship.

After upgrading, the performance of the same exact database queries deteriorated dramatically.

For example, a query that joins questions and answers by question id, used to take less than half second. After upgrade, it takes a MINUTE.

Since this is a development server, I can compare it to the production server, which still runs ubuntu 14.04 and where the same query takes only 0.38 seconds.

Here are the query plans

```
mysql> explain SELECT 
    ->     questions.id, questions.email, questions.topic, questions.question,  
    ->     questions.date, 
    ->     questions.deleted, 
    ->     questions.is_spam, 
    ->     questions.solved, 
    ->  
    ->     questions.tb_id, 
    ->     questions.tb_isbn, 
    ->     questions.tb_title, 
    ->     questions.tb_edition, 
    ->     questions.tb_chapter, 
    ->     questions.tb_problem, 
    ->  
    ->     solutions.id, solutions.author author, solutions.date, solutions.answer 
    -> FROM questions, solutions 
    -> WHERE 
    ->      questions.solved = 1 
    ->      AND questions.id = solutions.question 
    ->      AND questions.deleted != 1 
    ->      AND questions.is_spam != 1 
    -> ORDER BY solutions.date DESC 
    -> LIMIT 50;
```

On the "Good Server":

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | solutions | ALL    | solutions_by_question | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       | 650770 | Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | questions | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 4       | algebra.solutions.question |      1 | Using where    |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On the "Bad Server:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys         | key                   | key_len | ref                  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | questions | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY               | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                 | 482186 |     8.10 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | solutions | NULL       | ref  | solutions_by_question | solutions_by_question | 4       | algebra.questions.id |      1 |   100.00 | Using index condition                        |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The database contents are more or less the same, the development database is a backup of the server from last night.

Any ideas where I can start this wild goose chase understanding performance decline?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using an explicit join. Also, is the data the same?

Comment: You have very different output for the good server and the bad server ...

Comment: You must be running different versions of MYSQL because your results are different, one returns 640k rows the other 450k so the MySQL version is clearly to blame likely a documented change causing the query to return different results.  The "extra" and "key" column tells all you need to know.

Comment: What's wrong with the query specifically is out of scope here sadly.

Comment: Yes, the data is the same (one day difference). I am indeed running different versions of mysql, since, as the title and description say, I upgraded to a two year newer release of ubuntu. This looks like a very boring and garden variety query and I am surprised that mysql could not handle it in the 21st century, even though a two year old release handled it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you updated to a 16.04 Ubuntu server, and are using 5.7.12, you are encountering--at least in part--a bug eating up RAM, and some dynamic optimizations/default settings that are based off the server's available RAM and are set less than ideally. This has been problematic for lots of people, but especially for smaller server/vps with low RAM.

Search laracasts.com for MySQL 5.7 memory leak

https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/4gnj93/mysql_5712_ubuntu_1604_ridiculous_memory/

There are other issues, some of which 5.7.13 fixed of course...

http://mysqlentomologist.blogspot.com/2016/06/fun-with-bugs-43-bugs-fixed-in-mysql.html

There were also some different optimizations/changes made that will have an impact, depending on whether or not you use InnoDB or MyISAM. To give you an example, a recently installed VPS with 2 GB RAM that consumes around 320 MB RAM if you restart MySQL will slowly rise until consuming 1 GB on an idling app, in maintenance mode...with zero traffic or db queries (that was an OpenCart install which uses MyISAM...which I wouldn't want to wish on anyone trying to move forward...but that was a case of "hurry up and let's do this and use this and...."). And so that particular instance requires more $ and time to go back and deal with this same poor performance issue from MySQL because of a reliance on MyISAM in the app, memory leak, and some poor defaults the Oracle team threw out into the wild.

Sure, you want to probably optimize your queries and joins for the new updates. But, at the same time, you'll probably be wasting a great deal of effort and not accomplishing anything because of the underlying memory leaking like a sieve issue. If you're going to go through optimizations you might as well do it with a different MySQL server from the one causing problems for you.

Your options are, given how slow MySQL is at fixing bugs, are:

1) riding it out and waiting for repo updates that fix it

2) uninstall the current version and go back to a previous (but why?)

3) replace it with MariaDB or Percona

If you launch a new Ubuntu 16.04 server, I would change the repositories before connecting any remote administration user-agents or installing server management panels, so that you're on a MariaDB/Percona track. Or tracking the official MySQL repos rather than the Ubuntu repos, so you get fixes faster.

The safe and immediate solution (certainly smarter than prolonging your use of earlier versions with bugs and a major compatibility breakpoint in the release stream) is switching to MariaDB or Percona. Or, if you are using an app that can use PostgreSQL as well as MySQL, switch to Postgre--if it's something that's not impractical.

I would not waste my time trying to optimize the database until I had updated to 5.7.13 and monitored the results, or switched to MariaDB or Percona. Optimizing/troubleshooting 5.7.12 is just a black hole sucking at your time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, it's the bug [Excessive memory used in memory/innodb/os0file starting 5.7.8](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80772).

It is tracked in Ubuntu as [Excessive consumption RAM of mysqld daemon in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/akonadi/+bug/1576930), and there is also [a discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/4gnj93/mysql_5712_ubuntu_1604_ridiculous_memory/).